# can we get the data from five tables having a common id with one query?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

i want to get the data of five table having a common id from one query can we do this ,

for example tbl_student,tbl_batch,tbl_section,tbl_level,tbl_faculty all have a common id 
college_id

how can i get all the tables value with one query

if anybody can help me i would be greatful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly that sounds like a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

```
select * from tbl_student st 
join tbl_batch ba on ba.college_id=st.college_id
join tbl_section se on se.college_id=st.college_id
join tbl_level le on le.college_id=st.college_id
join tbl_faculty fa on fa.college_id=st.college_id
```

This is most probably not exactly the way you want to get the data because the data model would not make much sense. Hopefully you get the idea though.

Comment: Before you do that, you want to think about the cardinalities, though. If it is not 1:1:1 you will end up with more than one row per id (or missing ids).

Comment: In particular, it seems like you would get every "section" and every "faculty_se" in the whole college for every "student" of that college, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: you might want to use LEFT or OUTER joins if you want to account for instances where not every table has data for the student as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fields FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.id
  LEFT JOIN table4 ON table1.id = table4.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it won't make a lot of sense.

Your SQL query returns a 2-D table with the same columns for each row. If some of your rows are students and some of them are faculties, then there will be a bunch of columns that make sense for students but don't make sense for faculties, and for a faculty row those columns should be null.

The SQL to do this for two tables is:

```
SELECT t_F.college_id AS college_id, t_F.f_1, t_F.f_2, NULL   , NULL
    FROM tbl_Faculty AS t_F
UNION
SELECT t_S.college_id AS college_id, NULL   , NULL   , t_S.s_1, t_S.s_2
    FROM tbl_Student AS t_S
ORDER BY college_id
```

Then your results will look like:

```
college| Faculty field 1 |  2  | Student field 1 | 2
--------------------------------------------------------------
1      | abc             | def | NULL            | NULL
1      | abc             | ghi | NULL            | NULL
1      | NULL            | NULL| asdoifjas       | aosdifjasdf
1      | NULL            | NULL| asdoifjas       | aosdifjasdf
2      | abc321          | aaa | NULL            | NULL
2      | abc456          | bbb | NULL            | NULL
2      | NULL            | NULL| afasdfafs       | aosdifjasdf
2      | NULL            | NULL| asdoifjas       | aoffavsdfff
```

This doesn't make that much sense to me.